# LaTeXiT only renders the bottom half of the equation

Tags: math-mode, latexit

When I try to use LaTeXiT it only shows the bottom part of the equation, I have no idea what is causing this problem, I've searched the web about it but can't find anything related. It occurs not only on math eqs. but anything. I am on mac OS High Sierra.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please show a complete document then we can test it with the current TeX distribution. You must have some curious setting, because it won't be cut in the normal case.

Comment: @Red-Cloud I don't think LaTeXit works like normal LaTeX (the user does not create a full document). As far as I know it is an application that using LaTeX (somehow) can create images of equations to be used in a non-latex document. What you see on the image is the only think the user is typing in.

Comment: @Red-Cloud What you see in the screenshot is the whole document, daleif is right. But there you go just incase "$I_D = \frac{1}{2}\mu_n C_{ox}\frac{W}{L}V_{ov}$"

Comment: ah, ok, never used it.

Comment: tried it with Mojave 10.14.4 and LaTeXit with enabled "auto" button and had no problem

Comment: @daleif It has some default lines though, edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @Red-Cloud Thanks, can you please check if the default lines are similar too? I edited the screen shot in the post.

Comment: It had to somewhere, otherwise LaTeX cannot process it. It is a bit old fashioned in that it is using article instead of standalone. BTW: it might be interesting to know whether LaTeXit uses ghostscript in its processing, as there has been issues with some ghostscript versions

Comment: Is it only rendered incorrectly in the LaTeXiT window, or also when you drag it to another application or otherwise save/export the result?

Comment: @Marijn Not only on LaTeXiT, I only get the half of it whereever I paste or whichever format I copied it as.

Comment: @daleif I checked it by running $ gs command on terminal and it seemed fine to me. Here is the output:                                                                                                                                                                                     "GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
"

Comment: Just running gs isn't the issue, but I have seen that particular gs version mentioned elsewhere. So if LaTeXit is using gs to do its stuff that gs version might be the problem

Comment: @daleif you might have seen it at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488949/latexit-is-cropping-the-pdf, which seems to be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Yes, apparently there is a bug with Ghostscript 9.27. I solved the problem by installing the patch from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/mac/mactex?lang=en.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks a lot!